# I would like to fill an array with numbers using javascript with a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

"But I always double the numbers. so [1,1,2,2,3,3 .......] how can you do that? I am looking forward to the answer. "
Continuous with a number, the for loop is good. But how do I do it with double numbers?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Change your code from `arr.push(i);` to `arr.push(i);arr.push(i);` ?

Comment: @freedom, what's wrong with `arr.push(i, i)`?

Comment: @tao nothing at all.  If OP is having difficulty determining that 1x .push adds one value and can't determine for themselves that 2x .push adds 2 values, then giving them the *simplest* solution will help them move along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array to N, use:

```
let N = 10;
Array.from(Array(N).keys())
```

To double each value in any array:

```
[...yourArray.map(n => [n, n])].flat()
```

So, your solution:

```js
let n = 10;
const a = [...Array.from(Array(n).keys()).map(k => [k, k])].flat()

console.log(a)
```

To have it starting from `0`, not `1`, alter the mapping accordingly:

```js
let n = 10;
const a = [
  ...Array.from(Array(n).keys())
    .map(k => [k + 1, k + 1])
].flat()

console.log(a)
```

Arguably, the cleanest solution:

```js
function doubleArrayTo(n) {
  const a = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    a.push(i, i);
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(doubleArrayTo(10))
```

---

Out of curiosity, I tested their performance. Unsurprisingly, the `for` loop wins hands down over the spread syntax:

```js
function doubleFor(n) {
  const a = [];
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    a.push(i, i);
  }
  return a;
}
function doubleSpread(n) {
  return [
  ...Array.from(Array(n).keys())
    .map(k => [k + 1, k + 1])
  ].flat()
}

function run_test(fn, value) {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  fn(value);
  return performance.now() - t0;
}

[1e4, 1e5, 1e6, 1e7].map(value => {
  console.log(
    `(${value}): for => ${
      run_test(doubleFor, value)
    } | spread => ${
      run_test(doubleSpread, value)
    }`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

follow this code

```
var array = [];
for(int i = 0;i <= 10;i++) {
  array.push(i);
  array.push(i);//again
}
```

```js
var array = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  array.push(i,i);
}
console.log(array);
```

Edit

You can use multi input for array.push(i,i,i,....)

Comment: Why not `array.push(i,i)`?